# How does php know to start a new session

Tags: php, session

PHP will start a new session if a browser is closed and reopened.

The old session file is still kept in the session save directory, but a new session is started.

What does php look for in the browser to know that it must start a new session?

I guess what i am really asking is, what exactly does session_start() do under the hood

Comment: The session ID is saved in a cookie in the users browser. If none is found/one is invalid it creates one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-does-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used

Comment: I am pretty sure if there is no active session, ie any old sessions are expired, a session is started.

Comment: php doesnt look for anything, php get's a cookie with the name `PHPSESSID` or something like that. if the browser is closed this cookie will be destroyed.

Comment: So the browser deletes the cookie automatically unless php sepcifies an expiry date?

Comment: @MartyWallace depends on the browser's settings and how the cookie was set.

Comment: that's pertty much how normal cookies work. i suppose sessions work about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply answer your question, it looks for a cookie called [PHPSESSID](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) and if no cookie is supplied in the request, a call to [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) is made to initialize the cookie value.

The cookie is then persistently used throughout the lifetime of the browser.

Unless other settings apply, this is a stripped down version of the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie containing the session id is set without an expiry by default. This means it will expire when the browser is closed. So the session will be lost at that point since the client won't have the old session ID anymore.

Answer (score 0):

All you want to know is already written here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.
>
> When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will
>   call the open and read session save handlers. These will either be a
>   built-in save handler provided by default or by PHP extensions (such
>   as SQLite or Memcached); or can be custom handler as defined by
>   session_set_save_handler(). The read callback will retrieve any
>   existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will
>   be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION
>   superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back
>   to PHP session handling.

Basically, PHP writes a special file in the file system (usually in the /tmp directory) and gets the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

The session ID ([PHPSESSID](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name)) is saved in a cookie in the users browser. If none is found/one is invalid it creates one. The image below may be of some help in understanding what you want to know (it's from Chrome).

[image]

Once PHP gets this session ID, it looks for the corrisponding session which is stored in the session [save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) (normally `/tmp` on unix machines). It then gives you the ability to access the information stored in that session file using the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

The cookies are stored only if there is nothing outputted on the PHP page prior to the `session_start()` call. If there is something being outputted, the cookie is not stored and you need another method(as mentioned, `SQLite` or `MySQL`) to store those `UNIQUE` values and recognize and separate each user.