# Making a PHP variable global accross multiple web pages

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm fairly new to PHP so sorry if this is a naive question, but I want to build a php function library that utilizes a variable that is global across multiple pages. I'm using these 3 files to test:

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    function report()
    {
        echo "Value = ".$GLOBALS["var"]; 
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $var = "ABC";
    require "functions.php";
    echo "<h1>index.php</h1>";
    report();
?>
<br /><br />
<input type=button onClick="location.href='page2.php'" value="Page2">
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php   
    require "functions.php";
    echo "<h1>page2.php</h1>";
    report();
?>
```

The `report` function called by `index.php` echoes `Value = ABC` as expected. But when the `Page2` button is clicked, the `report` function called by `page2.php` displays an `Undefined index` error raised by `$GLOBALS["var"]` in `functions.php`.

I'd like to use `$GLOBALS["var"]` when it is referenced from `page2.php`. Can anyone tell me how to enable this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). $GLOBALS is only global within a script.

Comment: If you open `page2.php` you don't have `$GLOBALS["var"]` anywhere defined.

Comment: Bingo for `sessions`! I added: `session_start();` at the beginnings of `index.php` and `page2.php` and substituted `$_SESSION['var']` for all the global `var` references. Thanks Hobo Sapiens.

Comment: Rizier123, I'm not sure how to define `$GLOBALS["var"]` in `page2.php` without reintializing it and loosing the original value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, here are a few links you should read about `$_SESSIONS` variables.

- [PHP.net - Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)
- [StackoverFlow - How php sessions works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-do-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used)

I've update your code to make you an example.

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function report()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['var']))
        echo "Value = ". $_SESSION['var']; 
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
        session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        $_SESSION['var'] = "ABC";

        require('functions.php');
        echo "<h1>index.php</h1>";

        report();
    ?>
    <br><br>
        <input type="button" onClick="location.href='page2.php'" 
               value="Page2">
</body>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
         require ('functions.php');
         echo "<h1>page2.php</h1>";
         report();
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually, placing HTML above `session_start();` is considered as outputting before header, therefore it's best to first declare it `<?php session_start(); ?>` then followed by `<html>
<head>...` - Rerences http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Ok - seems everyone learned in this topic - I modify then code then. Edit : done.

Answer (score 4):

Recommended: Declare your variable.. Or use isset() to check if they are declared before referencing them.

Secondly you need to define a session

```
<?php
function report()
{
    echo "Value = ". **$_SESSION['var']**; 
}
?>
```

and use in in all your pages :)

ie, for page 1,

```
<?php
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['var'] = "XYZ";

        require('functions.php');

        report();
    ?>
```

and fot page2 also,

```
<?php 
session_start();

require ('functions.php');
report();
?>
```

Hope it helps :)