# Why session doesn't recognise manual change of cookie?

Tags: php

I am trying to fully understand sessions, and I conducted this test:

my code is:

test.php

```
<?
@session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['test'])) {

echo "test success";

}
?>
```

When I enter my cookie manually into my browser using an addon as:

```
PHPSESSID test
```

It does not recognise it.

Comment: `PHPSESSID` contains the session ID, not the session variable itself.

Comment: Session variables are stored on the server. The session ID is just a key used to find all the session variables in that session.

Comment: You need to go do some reading up on the very basics of how PHP sessions work … http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-do-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION is a "superglobal" (available everywhere) array that is tied with a cookie using a unique session id.

If you're wanting to reference cookie values you've set you'll need to use the $_COOKIE superglobal array.

You can read more about superglobals here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

And how $_SESSION and $_COOKIE works here:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

You cannot set values in the SESSION by using the browser like that. PHP is the only place you'll be able to set the 'test' key to a value, like true or false.

```
session_start();

// You could assign this based on the value of a cookie
$_SESSION['test'] = true;

if ($_SESSION['test']) {
    // this is a test session
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To see the result of your cookie change, do:

```
<?
@session_start();

if(session_id() == 'test') {
    echo "test success";
}
```

The cookie contains the session ID, individual session variables are stored on the server, using this ID and the variable name as keys (the default configuration uses a file named after the session ID).