# Is it safe to verify a form with the superglobal $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, ajax, session, web, session-variables

I have a form and when I submit it, I do an AJAX call to my server. 
On the server-side, I verify the informations by comparing them with some variables in the superglobale $_SESSION like below :

```
HeCanBuyIt = $ajaxData->priceProduct <= $_SESSION["user"]->moneyOfUser;
```

I am not sure if it is safe or not to do that (Can the user change the "moneyOfUser" variable in his session?).

I can also read the user from the database but it cost the time of a SELECT... I know it's not so slow but I prefer the fastest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All values in the `$_SESSION` variable are stored only on the server. The client is only given a session ID, which is stored in a cookie in their browser. There is no way for a user to view or manipulate the values in their `$_SESSION` unless you have explicitly coded that into your program.

See also: [How do PHP sessions work? (not "how are they used?")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-do-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was worried about the fact that some hackers could access to that variable but it seems that they can't according to you :)