# How does a webserver differenciates requests from different browsers on the same PC with boolean session variables?

Tags: php, apache, session

When you set a Boolean session variable when a user logs in in PHP like:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

Since this session variable is a Boolean and not a number, and Session variables are stored onto [the server not the user Computer](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), I expect that any browser(user) visiting that site where somebody(another browser) has already logged in, should automatically be logged in since the session variable has a Boolean value of **true** and not a unique number for different users and has already being set on the server.

How does the server identifies that a particular browser has not visited the site even though a Boolean Session has been set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do PHP sessions work? (not "how are they used?")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-do-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are unique per browser, not per computer / IP and so on. The browser will store a so called session cookie which will send back to the server with every request, allowing the server to identify the user. Every time you store something in the $_SESSION super global, this value is recorded in the current user's session, which is not available to others.

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question [How do PHP sessions work? (not "how are they used?")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-do-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used#1535712)

tldr;
In the general situation :

- the session id is sent to the user when his session is created.
- it is stored in a cookie (called, by default, PHPSESSID)
- that cookie is sent by the browser to the server with each request
- the server (PHP) uses that cookie, containing the session_id, to know which file corresponds to that user.