# Php, read/write SESSION simulteanously, two threads

Tags: php

in Php, there is a script, runs occasionally:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['x']++;
```

and something to use it, backround-service, runs "forever":

```
session_start();
do
{
    echo $_SESSION['x']; // never gets updated!
} while(true);
```

the problem is, the `echo` echoes the same result, like it never gets updated. But both are running. Maybe sessions should be reloaded somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do PHP sessions work? (not "how are they used?")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-do-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used)

Comment: Have you tried calling [`session_reset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-reset.php) inside the `do { ... }` loop?

Comment: I tried, but doesnt work, it "kills" the session. If I do "session_start();session_write_close();" then it works