# Is it possible to prevent cookies to be sent in every HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, browser

I recently found (here: [Does every web request send the browser cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336126/does-every-web-request-send-the-browser-cookies)) that every HTTP request contains the cookies related to a domain every time a request is made to that same domain.

Given this, what happens when the request is not sent through a browser but from Node.js, for example? Is it possible that no information is sent in the request?
Is it also possible to prevent it to be sent in the browser requests?

Comment: If you open a url that runs something that needs cookies to work properly, you must send the appropriate cookies irrespective of what technology your using.

Comment: what do you mean, "not sent through a browser but from node"? node is doing some kind of internal request, masquerading as the remote user?

Comment: For example, a XHR...

Comment: For future readers, there is an alternative to cookies which is not sent to the server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44149972/2570677

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Browsers**

**Is not possible to prevent browser to send cookies**.

This is why is generally it is [recommended](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) (Yahoo developer Best practice, see section Use Cookie-free Domains for Components) to serve static content like css, images, from a different domain that is cookie free.

> When the browser makes a request for a static image and sends cookies together with the request, **the server doesn't have any use for those cookies**. So they only **create network traffic for no good reason**. You should make sure static components are requested with cookie-free requests. Create a subdomain and host all your static components there.

---

**Programmatically**

**From any programming language**, instead, **you can choose** if you like to send cookies or not.

Cookie management is done by the programmer, because libraries are written to make single requests.

So if you make a first request that return cookies, you need to explicit read them, hold them locally somewhere, and eventually put them in a second request to the same server if you need.

So from NodeJS if you don't explicitly add cookies in your requests the http call doesn't hold them.

Comment: Explain it a little more: 1. Land on www. subdomain, for example www.yoursite.com and NOT yoursite.com (domain itself) and 2. serve the images and such from a subdomain such as cdn.yoursite.com. The cookies will be used only on www. and not on cdn. However when the visitor land on yoursite.com instead of www.yoursite.com, all cookies will be send to all subdomains. So when the user land on yoursite.com, you must redirect it to www.yoursite.com to keep cdn.yoursite.com (and other domains) cookie free. ;-) it is possible to avoid cookies on such files.

Answer (score 16):

You Can Use `Fetch` with the `credentials` option set to `omit` 
see

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent cookies from being sent in the response headers of your Node.js application, don't set any cookies in your server's response. If you are using a framework like Express.js, you can simply omit the Set-Cookie header when responding to a client request. For example:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();

// Middleware to remove cookies from request headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // Remove all cookies by clearing the `cookie` header
  req.headers.cookie = '';

  // Continue processing the request
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Now, req.headers.cookie is empty
  res.send('Cookies removed from request headers.');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score -4):

You can strip cookies with a proxy server.  For example our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will allow you to modify requests (and responses), and you could use this to clear the Cookie header in requests.

However, this will prevent a large number of websites from functioning properly, as cookies are used to transport session IDs so that the server can identify each connection / request your browser makes as being from the same "session".  HTTP itself does not have any concept of session.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who make WinGate.

Comment: not sure why the down-vote, OP wasn't clear about where the browsers are.  If you want to stop sending cookies on browsers under your control, or in a network under your control, then a proxy is a solution.  If the clients are on the internet, and you are the server, then the clients would only send you cookies if you previously set them with a Set-Cookie header, which is therefore under your control.