# SSO with Cognito and Amplify + Angular

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

This could be a duplicate question but I'm not able to resolve it.

We have three websites running on Angular 10:

**sso.mywebsite.com**

**dev.mywebsite.com**

**demo.mywebsite.com**

When somebody comes to **dev** or **demo** site, they click on login icon and redirects to **sso.mywebsite.com**. There user is authenticated with Cognito using Amplify + Angular.

Now the user is redirected back to the **dev** or **demo** site from where login was initiated. Here if the user is already authenticated from **sso** website, s/he should be redirected to the main pages of website which is not happening.

After some research on the internet, I found that **Amplify** should be able to load authentication data if **cookieStorage** is defined something like this in Angular:

```
export const environment = {
  AMPLIFY: {
    region: 'us-east-2',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-2_xxxxxx',
    authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    userPoolWebClientId: '2xxx6j8xxxx1u2dixxxxnge',
    cookieStorage: {
      domain: 'mywebsite.com',
      secure: false,
      path: '/',
      expires: 365,
    }
  }
};
```

The **cookieStorage** settings are same in all three websites. But Amplify still cannot read authentication data. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't `domain: 'mywebsite.com',` be `demo.mywebsite.com` and `dev.mywebsite.com`? the cookies won't get sent unless the domains match.

Comment: If I set domain to individual subdomain, will Amplify able to match them by domain name?

Comment: Cookies will not get sent unless it is an exact match. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336126/does-every-web-request-send-the-browser-cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with following settings:

Set **.mywebsite.com** instead of **mywebsite.com**

```
export const environment = {
  AMPLIFY: {
    region: 'us-east-2',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-2_xxxxxx',
    authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    userPoolWebClientId: '2xxx6j8xxxx1u2dixxxxnge',
    cookieStorage: {
      domain: '.mywebsite.com',
      secure: false,
      path: '/',
      expires: 365,
    }
  }
};
```